# Window innerWidth size change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I'm using the $watch listener function to check changes on the window inner width with the following code:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return $window.innerWidth;
}, function(value) {
   if(value <= 768){
        $scope.mobileSize = "mobile";      
   }else{
        $scope.mobileSize = "screen";
   }
   console.log(value);
});
```

it should then act on the DOM with some ng-show conditions like this one for example :

```
                <div ng-show="mobileSize == 'screen'">
                    ...
                </div>
```

But it only seems to affect the page when I reload it after resizing it. The console.log(value) also only changes when I refresh the page.

Is there any way to make this code work while the window is being resized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'm not a fan of using `$watch` because of its inefficiency. That said, if you're already using jQuery (or you're willing to use it) together with Angular, you can try this in your controller:

```
function setMobileSize(value) {
   console.log(value);
   if(value <= 350){
        $scope.mobileSize = "mobile";      
   }else{
        $scope.mobileSize = "screen";
   }
};

setMobileSize($window.innerWidth);

$(window).resize(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        setMobileSize($window.innerWidth);    
    });
});
```

EDIT:

If you do not wish to use jQuery, you may bind to the `resize` event directly.

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        setMobileSize($window.innerWidth);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I was told most of the jQuery functionalities were integrated to angularjs and that in most case it is possible to avoid using the jQuery library. I am quite new to angular and I can't really fin an alternative to the jQuery $(window).resize function. Any idea how I could do that ?

Comment: @Karly you are correct when you say that some jQuery functionality is integrated to AngularJS. However, Angular does use jQuery if it's available otherwise it uses a subset lib called JQLite. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using jQuery along with Angular. That said, anything you do outside of Angular you just make sure you understand how it relates to Angular's digest cycle and handle it accordingly. I've edited my answer to include a non-jQuery alternative.